# How do I change the background src of BlurImageView from one to another?

Tags: android

```
public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel){

    progressDialog.hide();
    Item item = channel.getItem();
    int resources = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/icon_" + item.getCondition().getCode(), null, getPackageName());
    Drawable weatherIcon = getResources().getDrawable(resources);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(weatherIcon);
    location.setText(service.getLocation());
    condiiton.setText(item.getCondition().getDescription());
    temperature.setText(item.getCondition().getTemperature() + "\u00B0" + channel.getUnits().getTemperature());

    blurImageView.setImageResource(0);
    if(item.getCondition().getDescription().contains("Cloud")){
       blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudy));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }else if(item.getCondition().getDescription().contains("Clear")){
        blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.open_sky));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }else if(item.getCondition().getDescription().contains("Rain")){
       blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rainy));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }else if(item.getCondition().getDescription().contains("Snow")){
        blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snowy));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }else if(item.getCondition().getDescription().contains("Sun")){
        blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sunny));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }else{
        blurImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.other));
        blurImageView.setBlur(10);
    }
}
```

Here, I'm trying to change the background src of BlurImageView by the condition mentioned below. Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you try to remove `blurImageView.setImageResource(0);` ? and what did you get it on screen after doing this?

Comment: Did you get any error messages in logcat?

Comment: From my point of view blurImageView.setImageResource(0) removes the resource of imageview but yeah, I tried to remove it also, still no working

Comment: No, I did not get any error